# PIG script: Expand a single row with a start and end date into multiple rows, one for each day

Tags: apache-pig

I need a PIG script to convert a single row that contains a campaign Id, start date, end date, and amount into multiple rows: one row for each day with an amount that has been allocated to that day.  So for example, schema is:
campaignId, startDate, endDate, totalAmount

and my my input row has:

```
1,2015-01-01,2015-01-10,10000
```

I need to create individual rows for each day of this "campaign" that divides the totalAmount across each day into a schema like this:

campaignId, date, amount

```
1,2015-01-01,1000
1,2015-01-02,1000
1,2015-01-03,1000
```

... etc one row for each day of the campaign

I am hoping I can use a nested foreach and a DaysBetween function.

Answer (score 1):

This problem will be little bit difficult to solve using standard pig, the challenge will be dynamic date generation between two dates.  Suppose if the months are overlapped(`ie, 2015-01-28 to 2015-02-06`) then pig doesn't have any intelligence to generate 4 days from Jan and 6 days from Feb.

To solve this problem, one option could be move the date generation part to Custom UDF, parse the inputs and generate the intermediate dates.

**Example1:** Only `one input` and dates are `not overlapped`

**input:**

```
1,2015-01-01,2015-01-10,10000
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER PARSEDATE.jar; 
A = LOAD 'input' Using PigStorage(',') AS (campaignId:int,startDate,endDate,totalAmount:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE campaignId,DaysBetween((datetime)endDate,(datetime)startDate)+1 AS cnt, totalAmount,TOBAG(*) AS mybag;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE campaignId,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(mypackage.PARSEDATE(BagToString(mybag)),'#')),(int)(totalAmount/cnt) AS totalAmount;
STORE C INTO 'output' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**Output:**

```
1,2015-01-01,1000
1,2015-01-02,1000
1,2015-01-03,1000
1,2015-01-04,1000
1,2015-01-05,1000
1,2015-01-06,1000
1,2015-01-07,1000
1,2015-01-08,1000
1,2015-01-09,1000
1,2015-01-10,1000
```

**Example2:** `two inputs`, `first input` is `not overlapped` and `second input` is `overlapped`

**input1:**

```
1,2015-01-01,2015-01-10,10000
2,2015-01-28,2015-02-06,10000
```

**PigScript:**

```
REGISTER PARSEDATE.jar; 
A = LOAD 'input1' Using PigStorage(',') AS (campaignId:int,startDate,endDate,totalAmount:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE campaignId,DaysBetween((datetime)endDate,(datetime)startDate)+1 AS cnt, totalAmount,TOBAG(*) AS mybag;
C = FOREACH B GENERATE campaignId,FLATTEN(TOKENIZE(mypackage.PARSEDATE(BagToString(mybag)),'#')),(int)(totalAmount/cnt) AS totalAmount;
STORE C INTO 'output1' USING PigStorage(',');
```

**Output:**

```
1,2015-01-01,1000
1,2015-01-02,1000
1,2015-01-03,1000
1,2015-01-04,1000
1,2015-01-05,1000
1,2015-01-06,1000
1,2015-01-07,1000
1,2015-01-08,1000
1,2015-01-09,1000
1,2015-01-10,1000
2,2015-01-28,1000
2,2015-01-29,1000
2,2015-01-30,1000
2,2015-01-31,1000
2,2015-02-01,1000
2,2015-02-02,1000
2,2015-02-03,1000
2,2015-02-04,1000
2,2015-02-05,1000
2,2015-02-06,1000
```

You need to compile the below java code and generate `PARSEDATE.jar` file and include into your pig script. I just wrote this code temporarily, you can optimize according to your need.

**PARSEDATE.java**

```
package mypackage;
import java.io.*;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.joda.time.LocalDate;
import org.joda.time.Days;

public class PARSEDATE extends EvalFunc<String> {
        public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {

                //Get the input String from request
                String inputString = (String)input.get(0);

                //Get Startdate from second column
                String startDate = inputString.split("_")[1];

                //Get enddate from third column
                String endDate = inputString.split("_")[2];

                LocalDate st = new LocalDate(startDate);
                LocalDate et = new LocalDate(endDate);

                //Calculate days between given dates
                int days = Days.daysBetween(st, et).getDays()+1;

                //Append all the dates as String
                String output="";
                for (int index=0; index < days; index++) 
                {
                   //Each dates are delimited by '#', so it will be easy to parse in the pig script.                     
                   output = output+"#"+st.plusDays(index).toString();
                }
                return output;
        }
}
```

Comment: Doesn't the DaysBetween function in PIG handle the number of days between the two dates?  This is the function I was expecting to be useful: https://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.11.1/func.html#days-between>